# JS - print only <div> from another file

Tags: javascript, file, html, printing

Now I'm using *onClick="window.print(); return false;"*...

But I need to print a *div* content form another file.

Example:
I have the file *buttons.html*, but in this file is my print button with *window.print()*.
I need when this button is pressed to print only *div* content (e.g. *div id=...*), but from the file *index.html*.

I hope you understand me.

*Please give more detailed code, I'm new.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

```
function printDivs()
{
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var text = "";

    for( var i=0; i<divs.length; i++ )
    {
        var div = divs[i];

        if (typeof(div.nodeName) !== "undefined")
        {
            text = text + div.innerHTML + "<br /><br />";
        }
    }

    document.body.innerHTML = text;

    window.print();
}
```

That should work, as long if its executed on the same page. Is this what you mean or do you mean something else?

You can call this script by using: Print for example.

Answer (score 0):

That's unusual, but certainly possible:

```
// buttons.html, Using jQuery
$('button').click(function() {
  $.get('index.html', function(h) {
    $('body').html($('div#content', h).html());
    window.print();
  }, "html");
});
```

Comment: But I use an image instead button, so my image is <a gref=""><img src=""></a> how to integrate this with the script?

Comment: You will have to customize both `button` and `div#content` above to match your setup. See [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) for more details concerning [jQuery](http://jquery.com) selectors.